# Declaring, changing, and adding to an array of a list of structs in C

Tags: arrays, list, c

I've created a struct and the struct has a metric on it. I am generating a series of these structs and I want to sort them into an array based on this metric. Basically, if the metric is 0, I want it in the list in the [0] slot of the array, if the metric is 14, I want it in the list in the [14] slot of the array. The bound on the metric (size of the array) is variable based on the same variable that the structs are generated off of, so I need the array to be declared dynamically with malloc. I've been experimenting with how to get this array of lists of my struct. I can't figure it out. I've googled the problem and haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Also, once I have the array, how do I add another element to the list of a particular array cell? And then go back through and compare all elements of the list in the i th cell to the elements of the (n-i)th cell?

Comment: is your array very large with a high proportion of empty cells?

Comment: The array is proportional to N in size and I'd have to estimate that only N/log(N) cells will have entries.

Comment: and how large can n get?  I am trying to assess whether the  array is wasting too much space because of empty entries. That is why using a hash table may be useful: to save on array empty entries.  My feeling is that you need to learn the use  of pointers in C and to build lists with them.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a *hash table*, also sometimes known as an *associative array* or a *dictionary*. This is a data structure that looks like an array but can get any (hashable) datatype as an index; your struct is hashable due to your metric. Dynamic hash tables, such as python's dictionary, will resize on their own to fit their contents.

If you want to keep several elements in each cell, simply make each cell a list. In python or any other high-level language you would simply use a list datatype. On lower-level languages, you can use linked lists instead.

Comment: I actually coded this in python first and used lists.
Can you give me an example of a hash table with each cell as a list. And then how to access these lists? I've never used hash tables before and learn much quicker from examples.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, and your comment to @Yuval, it seems that you can investigate this with Python, and if I understand correctly, that you may have more than one `struct` that has the same `metric` value, which you want to now group together into a list (if any of that is wrong, correct me, and I'll try to edit as necessary).

@Yuval makes a good point - this seems to be about using hash tables/dictionaries, which are very helpful once you get used to them. Basically, instead of accessing elements simply by some index, ranging from 0 to `N-1` or similar, they give you a way to associate a key with a value or list of values.

Here's some Python code, assuming you've already made your `struct`s, and that they have a `metric` attribute:

```
## build the hahtable
metricDict = dict() ## or: metricDict = {}
for struct in structs:
    key = struct.metric
    metricDict[key] = struct

## access your items:
for metric, struct in metricDict.items():
    ## ... whatever you want to do
```

A few key points here:

1) these results will likely appear to come out of your dictionary "randomly" - the metric won't be ordered consecutively. This has to do with some of the inner details on how hash tables actually work, and an in-depth explanation is probably overkill for now, but the main point to remember is that dictionaries are unsorted. To get around this, when you access elements:

```
for metric, struct in sorted(metricDict.items()):
    ## whatever you want to do
```

2) This (silently) ignored the issue of multiple `struct`s having the same value for `metric` - it only held on to the last `struct` with that `metric`, overwriting the previous ones. There are simple ways around this, as well - instead of storing a single value, you can store a list of values (or, I might phrase that: you are storing a value that is a list of structs)

```
metricDict = dict()
for struct in structs:
    key = struct.metric
    if key in metricDict:
        metricDict[key].append(struct) ## add the struct to the list
    else:  ## first time we've seen key
        metricDict[key] = list() ## or metricDict[key] = []
        metricDict[key].append(struct)
```

I've tried to make that a little more explicit than necessary. This idea of aggregating and grouping things together is common enough that Python even has a module that makes things a bit easier:

```
import collections
metricDict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for struct in structs:
    key = struct.metric
    metricDict[key].append(struct)
```

The `metricDict` is smart enough to know that if it hasn't seen a key yet, instead of throwing an error, it just creates a default - an empty list, in this case - and then adds your `struct` to that list.

Now for accessing your list of structs:

```
for metric, structs in sorted(metricDict.items()):
    ## print(metric)
    for struct in structs:
        ## whatever you wanted to do
        ## print(struct)
```